# How to print an arraylist and remove its duplicates in java

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates

I'm currently solving an exercise from https://java-programming.mooc.fi/part-5/4-objects-and-references (Exercise: archive) and it tells me to print only the non-duplicate identifiers of the list. If the identifiers are already found in the list, only the first one will be printed. Even though there are duplicate identifiers in my input it will still print each item of the `ArrayList`. How can I fix this?

**Desired Output:**

[image: Desired Output]

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

        String identifier = "";

        String name = "";

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Identifier? (empty will stop)");

            identifier = scanner.nextLine();

            if (identifier.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }

            System.out.println("Name? (empty will stop)");

            name = scanner.nextLine();

            if (name.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }

            if (!items.contains(identifier)) {
                items.add(identifier + ": " + name);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("==Items==");
        for (String i : items) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't add `identifier` to `items` so it will never contain `identifier` (just `identifier: name`).

Comment: Your problem is in the third if statement. You are concatenating the identifier with the name while adding thus even if the identifier is the same but with a different name your statement about checking if the identifier exists in your list or not makes no sense because it will have another name thus it doesn't match with the other input. Now i pointed out the problem and now  to stimulate your brain  id like to know how would you solve it :) and it would be good for your future post to add your output so we can spot the problem Easily....

Comment: For best performance, use a `Set` to keep track of the identifiers you've already printed.